# Countable dense subset of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

$(C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n), ||.||_{L^p})$ is separable as a subset of $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$, which is itself separable ($1<p<\infty$).

Hence, what are the countable dense subsets of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$?

I am not looking for all countable dense subsets, but rather, what are the well-known sets of functions that separate $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$?

Comment: Are you after *all*  countable dense subsets of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos, I edited the post accordingly

Comment: I would check out the Haar wavelets. What you're asking is not them as they are not smooth, but you can adapt them to suit your needs. (Use a bump function as the mother wavelet, do some Haar tricks to get daughter wavelets and then discretize in width and where they're centered.)

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this.

Comment: I don't think your first sentence is correct. The metric on $C_c^\infty, L^p$ are quite different. (btw which metric on $C_c^\infty$ did you mean?)

Comment: Take all polynomials with rational coefficients, truncated (smoothly) to compact subsets of $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @PhoemueX - that is on the right track, but there are uncountably many compact subsets, and uncountably many bump functions for truncating them, so you don't have a countable dense subset yet.

Comment: @zhw $C_c^\infty$ can be isometrically embedded in any $L^p$. So the $L^p$ norm as a metric

Comment: Take simple functions supported in a $[a_1,b_1]\times\dots\times [a_n,b_n]$ for rational endpoints and mollify with some fixed bump function and $1/n$ as radii?

Comment: Not just isometrically embeddable, it is directly a subset of these spaces. So you intended some $L^p$ norm as giving the metric? That is worth making clear in the statement. (Also note $L^\infty$ is not separable.)

Comment: @PaulSinclair  You only have to worry about the compact sets $\{|x|\le m\}, m=1,2,\dots$ and for fixed $m,$ the bump functions

$$g_l(x) = \left (\exp {\frac{-1}{|x|^2-m^2}}\right )^{1/l}, l = 1,2,\dots$$

Comment: @zhw good points, thanks, I edited the question accordingly

Comment: @PaulSinclair Typo, that should have been $$g_l(x) = \left (\exp {\frac{-1}{m^2-|x|^2}}\right )^{1/l}, l = 1,2,\dots$$

Comment: @zhw - yes, I was only pointing out to PhoemueX that some such reduction would be necessary for his otherwise-correct comment.

Comment: @zhw  Do you have a reference to this?  These are dense in the $L^p$ sense of in the $C^{\infty}$-metric sense?

Comment: @James_T It's in the $L^p$ sense.

Comment: @zhw Oh, that's unfortunate.  If you know of an example in the sup-sense I have a post here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366983/known-dense-subset-of-schwartz-like-space-and-c-c-infty

Comment: @James_T I think what PhoemueX said works for $C^\infty_c$ in the $\sup$ norm

Comment: Oh really?  Do you have a reference or know what that construction is called?

Answer (score 1):

Great question.

Let me give you a taste of how to prove it. Let $\mathrm{X}$ be a metrisable, separable, locally compact space. Then, there exists an increasing family $\mathrm{K}_n$ of compact subsets of $\mathrm{X}$ such that $\mathrm{K}_n \subset \mathring{\mathrm{K}}_{n + 1}.$

Denote by $\mathscr{K}(\mathrm{X}; \mathrm{K})$ the set of real-valued function with support contained in the compact set $\mathrm{K}.$ If you find a dense subsequence for each $\mathscr{K}(\mathrm{X}; \mathrm{K}_n)$ ($n \in \mathbf{N}$), then you are done.

Canonically, $\mathscr{K}(\mathrm{X}; \mathrm{K}_n)$ is identified with the subspace of $\mathscr{C}(\mathrm{K}_{n + 1})$ of functions vanishing outside $\mathrm{K}_n,$ where $\mathscr{C}(\mathrm{L})$ is the the space of real-valued continuous function defined on $\mathrm{L}.$ Finally, a common application of Stone-Weierstrass theorem gives a dense subset of $\mathscr{C}(\mathrm{L}).$